# how to use r to extract gwas data from phenoscanner database

Tags: r

I am getting error in read.table message when I typed

```
extract.pheno.csv(exposure = "log(eGFR creatinine)", 
                  pmidE = 26831199, ancestryE = "European",
                  outcome = "Tanner stage", pmidO = 24770850, 
                  ancestryO = "European", file = path.noproxy)
```

to extract data.

Kindly help me

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What is the error? What package are you using? How does your data differ from the data from function's help file?